# Why is it defined that $(-1)!!=1$?

Tags: factorial

Why is it defined that $(-1)!!$ equal to $1$, where $!!$ is the [double factorial](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DoubleFactorial.html)?

I've only seen it defined that $(-1)!!=1$, but I don't see *why* it should be so.

Comment: A better question might be "Why is $(-1)!!$ defined to be $1$?"

Comment: @robjohn I agree. That would be a *much* better question. I remember I used to get annoyed that people would say $0!=1$ because it's defined that way--why? Because it's convenient, they would say. The reason behind the definition here is much more interesting I think. :)

Answer (score 4):

Note that $(n+2)!!=(n+2)\,n!!$. Since $1!!=1$, the logical extension would be $(-1)!!=1$.

Comment: This can be found, as $n!!=n\times(n-2)!!$, in [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_factorial#Negative_arguments).

Comment: Since the OP is gone and the question has been improved, can we stop what seems to be the vengeful downvoting?

Comment: Would the recent downvoter care to comment? The question is old enough that it doesn't seem this is vengeful. Certainly, one can say this is the definition, but it also follows from the recurrence for $n!!$

Answer (score 1):

First, the post is low quality. Please write it in a better style.

Also, by definition, $(-1)!!=0!!=1$

This is by definition, as $0!=1$ by definition.

Comment: There are reasons that these definitions are made. In this case, the rule defining $n!!$ can be logically extended to $(-1)!!$. There *is* a similar extension for $0!$, but that one is easier to understand since it can be seen as the product of the first $0$ positive integers, and empty products are usually taken to be $1$.

Comment: @robjohn Everyone's downvoting because he actually changed his question. I answered it when it was first posted, and one might want to look at his edits.

Comment: Note that the OP is no longer around. Someone else was trying to improve the question (taking care of the low quality aspect). However, I was commenting on the claim that the reason was "by definition" when there are logical reasons behind that definition.

Comment: Indeed. My answer was downvoted, too, even though it applies equally to the improved question.

Comment: Oh, sorry then. I misunderstood your point.

Comment: No worries. Although I made a comment about why I did not find your answer complete, I did not downvote your answer.